# How to add parameters to url_for?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fusioncharts

I'm calling this chunk of code in a Rails 2.3 app view to render a FusionChart:

```
<div id="cust_progress"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var activity = new FusionCharts("/flash/MSLine.swf", "chart1Id", "600", "450", "0", "1");
  activity.setDataURL("<%=url_for(:controller=>'custs',:action=>'progress_line_chart', :id=>params[:id])%>");
  activity.render("cust_progress");
</script>
```

At the scope where this code is called, I have a few other parameters that I need to pass to the data url.  I haven't been able to find any way to get those parameters in to my progress_line_chart controller action.

I believe the url_for method doesn't allow you to pass more parameters, so I'm at a bit of a loss for what to do, I have tried a few other URL creation methods but haven't found anything that works.

Can this be done?  Global variable is a dirty solution but it's what I have temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

pass the data as a string, rather than a symbol

`"data-url" => "your data"`

Comment: That works for a single parameter, but it doesn't seem to take anything after the '&' for example:

<% durl = "/custs/progress_line_chart/5?end=123&start=456" %>

I have something in params[:end] but params[:start] is nil, using params.inspect I see:

{"action"=>"progress_line_chart", "end"=>"123", "id"=>"5", "controller"=>"custs", "FCTime"=>"684"}

Comment: To add - The problem was encoding the URL, once that was done I could pass multiple parameters, the next problem that popped up was that any time parameter I tried to pass would break the URL, for reasons unknown to me the ':' encoded in to %3A causes my URL to continue breaking, annoying but avoidable by using a custom time format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question as you can specify any parameters you like to `url_for`:

```
url_for(:controller => 'custs', :action => 'progress_line_chart',
        :id => params[:id], :some => "other", :data => "goes", :here => true)
```

It will append the unrecognised path components as a query string.

Comment: That's correct, but I think the problem is with the setDataUrl() function, it seems to strip everything after the '&' in the query string.  So I can pass a single parameter and no more.  I think the problem has to do with encoding and escaping the characters out properly.  I believe I used CGI.escape